# xpages showing an element depending on two dates

Tags: xpages

My desire is to show/hide a div element depending on two inputTexts having `<xp:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">`. These fields are binded to some sessionScopes and they are displayed using dialog element.

So, I tried the following code inside the div rendered property:

```
var data1 = sessionScope.searchDate1;
//var data1 = getComponent("inputText3").getValue(); 
var data2 = sessionScope.searchDate2;
//var data1 = getComponent("inputText4").getValue();

if (( data1 != "") && (data2 != ""))
{
if (@Date(data1).before( data2 ) ||  @Date(data1).equals( data2 ))
    { return true; }

else 
    {return false; }
}
```

Every inputText event ( onChange) will refresh the mainpanel of the dialog, which contains the div also.

I'm getting : `'@Date()' is null`. Is this because I'm showing firstly the dialog? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (( data1 != "") && (data2 != ""))
```

to

```
if (data1 && data2)
```